# Multiple Ajax call with foreach

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have below code and it is working fine, Just wanted to improve the performance since it is taking so long to load data. Any suggestions?

So overall, function A will return the set of records, I have to make another call for each record which I got a response from Function A. and Same Function B each response input to Function C.

In simple language it it joins from 3 different data sources with a primary key and secondary key relationship.

Sample code.

```
function A()
{
    $.ajax({
        url: <URL>,
        type: "GET",
        headers: requestHeaders,
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.d.results.length > 0) {
                $.each(data.d, function (indexA, valueA) {
                    function B(valueA.<fieldname>);
                });
            }
        },
        error: function (data) {
            alert(data.responseJSON.error.message.value);
        }
    });
}
function B(inputfromFuncA)
{
    $.ajax({
        url: <URL> + inputfromFuncA, 
        type: "GET",
        headers: requestHeaders,
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.d.results.length > 0) {
                $.each(data.d, function (indexB, valueB) {
                    function C(valueB.<fieldname>);
                });
            }
        },
        error: function (data) {
            alert(data.responseJSON.error.message.value);
        }
    });
}
function C(inputfromFuncB)
{
    $.ajax({
        url: <URL> + inputfromFuncB, 
        type: "GET",
        headers: requestHeaders,
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.d.results.length > 0) {
                $.each(data.d, function (index, value) {
                    //Binding value to HTML Source 
                });
            }
        },
        error: function (data) {
            alert(data.responseJSON.error.message.value);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Without knowing details of what the ajax calls do it's hard to say if they can be optimised.

Comment: You should know asynchronous behaviour of javascript execution for bloked services like ajax , file read etc